# Proving in computability if L is subset of RE and infinity there is A ⊆ L and decidable

Tags: computer-science, computability, decidability

I'm trying to prove this in Computability:
if $L$ is a subset of Recursively Enumerable \ Recursively ($RE \setminus R$) and $L$ is infinite,
so there is $A \subseteq L$, which is infinite and decidable.
I don't even have any idea where to start, I understand I need to minimize $L$ to a decidable set.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Hi, do you maybe mean "if $L$ is a set that is recursively enumberable but not recursive..."? A subset of $RE \setminus R$ is a set of sets, and recursive/r.e. sets are usually sets of natural numbers..